# Creating custom web scraping tool to count unique words in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a function that has 2 arguments, a web URL, and a search word. The function should print out the number of times the word is seen on the page.

I am currently unsure of what I'm doing wrong, as my output isn't giving me neither an error nor an output...

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen

class customWebScraper(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self, searchWord, desiredURL):
      HTMLParser.__init__(self)
      self.searchWord= ''
      self.desiredURL = ''


def scrapePage(searchWord, desiredURL):
  wordCount = 0
  if searchWord.count(searchWord) > 0:
      wordCount += 1
      print(wordCount)

searchWord= ''
desiredURL = ''

urlContents = urlopen(desiredURL).read().decode('utf-8')

parseURL = customWebScraper(searchWord, desiredURL)
parseURL.feed(urlContents)
```

So if a user types:

customWebScraper('name','http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm')

it *should* output: 6

Comment: The page has only one occurrence of 'name' in the link you specified

Comment: What is `scrape_page()`? Where is it being used. Another thing to wonder is why in `__init__()` you are setting `self.searchWord` and `self.desiredURL` to an empty string. Next question, where in `scrape_page()` do you use the url? what is `searchTerm` in the if statement? The fact that this script does not return errors suggests to me that either `scrape_page()` isn't being called, or errors are being suppressed, because as written, that method should be throwing NameError in the if statement.

Comment: @SamRockett sorry I made a few mistakes and edited the post to display the function I currently have

Comment: `searchWord.count(searchWord)` will always be exactly 1. You are asking a string to count how many instances of itself that it contains. `scrape_page` is still never called, which I assume is what is (supposed to be) doing the counting.
Using a custom HTMLParser here does not seem like a productive option. It is reasonable to use it to parse the html into a tree to traverse (and extract text from) but it should be exactly that, a parser, not a counter. I would consider looking up how to extract the visible text from the html tree, and then feeding that into a counting function.

Comment: @SamRockett I would like to get a working class that parses the page and a function that counts the number of instances of a specific word though. Is that not possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example script that defines the function you want.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

class customWebScraper:
    def __init__(self, searchWord, desiredURL):
        self.searchWord = searchWord
        self.desiredURL = desiredURL

    def scrapePage(self):
        url_content = urlopen(self.desiredURL).read().decode('utf-8')
        return url_content.lower().count(self.searchWord.lower())



parseURL = customWebScraper('name', 'http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm')
count = parseURL.scrapePage()
print('"{}" appears in {} exactly {} times'.format(parseURL.searchWord, parseURL.desiredURL, count))
```

when I run it the output is:

> "name" appears in http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm exactly 6 times

I assumed you wanted case-insensitive match because in the page you provided, `name` appears 6 times only if you also count `appName`, etc.
[image: name 6 matches]

Comment: I can edit this code to be used as a class, but as it is completely stateless I don't see why a function wouldn't be enough. if because of other requirements you must have it in a class, please tell me.

Comment: To add to this, you can count instances of just the word `name` instead of substrings with a regex search `len(re.findall(r"\b{}\b".format(term), url_content, re.I))`

Comment: @Adam.Er8 yes precisely, other requirements dictate a class to be made

Comment: @SamRockett yup, I also went for it at the beginning but given the example I changed it to the simple substring match

Comment: @LordQuackingStick I edited my answer so now it creates a class, with a function on it. the function can be called as many times as needed, every time it will re-perform the request and count (helpful if the site's content changes frequently)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 is it at all possible to have the scrapePage function outside of the class? Or must it be inside in order for it for it to function they way I'd like it to?

Comment: There must be some function inside the class that does this, and can be called however we want. And then you can definitely def scrapePage outside of the class that uses it (just what I currently do in "main")

Comment: @Adam.Er8 what do you mean by 'main'?

Answer (score 2):

If you must use a subclass of HTMLParser, you can implement the counting logic by overriding `handle_data`.

```
class CountingParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, term):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.term = term.lower()
        self.total = 0

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.total += data.lower().count(self.term)

counter = CountingParser(name)
counter.feed(url_content)
print(counter.total)
```

The key difference between this and doing a search on the raw html is that this will not count meta occurences of the search term (such as in HTML tags)